# Blazor error Sorry, there's nothing at this address

Tags: .net, blazor

I have created a Blazor Webassembly in VS 2022 .net 7, using the default template, I will be using it to do some testing. However, I'm running into an issue, I create a simple Component Page \Pages\DialogTestPage.razor and the code looks like this

Code for DialogTestPage.razor

```
`@page "/dialogtestpage"

  <PageTitle>Alert</PageTitle>

  <h3>Dialog Test Page</h3>

@code {

}`
```

Navmenu.rezor code

```
`<div class="top-row ps-3 navbar navbar-dark">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">BlazorWAModalDialog</a>
    <button title="Navigation menu" class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</div>
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass nav-scrollable" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
<nav class="flex-column">
    <div class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
            <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
        </NavLink>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
            <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
        </NavLink>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
            <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
        </NavLink>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item px-10">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="dialogtestpage">
            <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Modal Dialog Boot Strap
        </NavLink>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>

@code {
private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

private void ToggleNavMenu()
{
    collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
}
}`
```

When I select the option Modal Dialog Boot Strap, I get the following results.
Sorry, there is nothing at this address

Here is what I have try to fix this issue.

1. Clean the solution
2. Rebuild solution
3. check routing in the App.razor
4. Uninstalled VS 2022 and reinstalled. (Version 17.5.4 running on windows 10 and 11)
5. Tryed using one of my other computers, with the same result

Comment: Did you check that `DialogTestPage.razor` is not excluded in your .csproj file?

Comment: This code, as shown here, should work. But "dialogtest" makes me think we are not seeing the full code. Create a [mre] in a _new_ Project. Then compare.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on your Blazor page in the solution explorer and choose Properties from the context menu.
2. Make sure "Build Action" is set to Content.
3. Run the Blazor application and access the page.